# What is the best way to visualise the comparison between these two data sets?

Tags: data-visualization, methodology

I have two data sets that I need to compare.
One set is the number of holdings in my library by collection (e.g. Adult Fiction - 10k copies, Child Fiction - 5k copies etc.).
My other data set is number of loans per month by collection (e.g. Adult fiction in Jan - 1.7k loans, Child fiction in Jan - 600 loans etc).

I am looking for a way to compare these two data sets to each other in a way that will visualize where our collections are working (high loan rate / popularity + high number of holdings) and where it isn't working (high number of holdings but low rate of loans / popularity).

What is a statistical model that I can use to compare these two sets of data in a way that any layman can look at the results and clearly see what is working and what isn't across all book collections, in comparison to each other.

Comment: Welcome. Do you want to model the relationship or visualize (graphically) the two sources of information?

Comment: I want to model the relationship, thanks!